# MySQL - why cannot I add foreign key to multiple columns pointing to one column?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table called `foodlist`, which contains foods:

```
CREATE TABLE `foodlist` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Example data:

```
id | name
1  | Apple
2  | Banana
3  | Cinnamon
```

Then I have a table of combination of foods you can eat together:

```
CREATE TABLE `foodlist-also_eat` (
  `originalFood` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `alsoFood` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`originalFood`,`alsoFood`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

That means, that if you can eat apple with banana, the entry is:

```
originalFood | alsoFood
1              2
```

Now, what I want to do, is to add foreign keys in my `foodlist-also_eat` table.

I can add one for `originalFood`:

```
ALTER TABLE `foodlist-also_eat`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`originalFood`) REFERENCES `foodlist` (`id`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

> Query OK.

However, I **cannot** continue adding one for `alsoFood`:

```
ALTER TABLE `foodlist-also_eat`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`alsoFood`) REFERENCES `foodlist` (`id`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

> Source and target columns must have the same data type, there must be an index on the target columns and referenced data must exist.
>   Table './dev@002dfood/foodlist@002dalso_eat' already exists

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation on [*`Foreign key constraints`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> If the CONSTRAINT symbol clause is given, the symbol value must be unique in the database. If the clause is not given, InnoDB creates the name automatically.
>
> Note that as of version 5.0.38, InnoDB allows two or more foreign keys on the column, they may reference diffrent tables/columns. It even allows foreign keys with the same definition, but different constraint name.

Define a *unique* name for each of the constraint being defined.

```
ALTER TABLE `foodlist-also_eat`
ADD constraint fk_of_flae 
    FOREIGN KEY (`originalFood`) 
    REFERENCES `foodlist` (`id`)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE `foodlist-also_eat`
ADD constraint fk_af_flae 
    FOREIGN KEY (`alsoFood`) 
    REFERENCES `foodlist` (`id`)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I wonder why this isn't done automatically, or, on the other hand, why on some tables the similar scenario did work automatically (using adminer 4).